# Fallo con metodo de prueba en java

Tags: java, junit

Al realizar un método de prueba me da un error y no encuentro el fallo, adjunto el código del método y de los métodos usados.
Pretendo establecer un método que me devuelva la edad, las dos primeras letras del nombre en mayúsculas, las cuatro primeras letras del appellido en mayúsculas y un código de edad así como probar el correcto funcionamiento del mismo.
el error me da en el assertEquals.
Código de la prueba:

```
  @Test
public void testGetHushCodeShortSurname(){
    Person person1 = new Person();
    person1.setAge(person1.INITIAL_AGE);
    person1.setName(person1.INITIAL_NAME);
    person1.setSurname("yi");
    assertEquals(person1.getAge()+"-"+person1.getUpperName()+"-"+person1.getUpperSurname()+"-"+person1.getAgeCode());
}
```

Códigos de los métodos:
(ADULTHOOD_AGE = 18, RETIREMENT_AGE = 65)

```
protected String getAgeCode(){
    if(getAge() <= ADULTHOOD_AGE){
        return "CHILD";
    } else if (getAge() > ADULTHOOD_AGE && getAge() < RETIREMENT_AGE){
        return "ADULT";
    } else 
        return "RETIRED";
}

protected String getUpperName() {
    if(getName().length() > 2){
        return getName().substring(0,2).toUpperCase();
    } else 
    return getName().toUpperCase();
}

protected String getUpperSurname(){
    if (getSurname().length() > 4){
        return getSurname().substring(0,4).toUpperCase();
    } else
        return getSurname().toUpperCase();
}

public String getHushCode(){
    String code = "" + this.getAge()+"-" +getUpperName()+ "-" +getUpperSurname()+ "-"+getAgeCode()+"";
    return code;
}
```

El error es el siguiente:
[image]

Comment: Hola, ¿Podrías poner que error te da? Gracias

Comment: ya esta añadido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error que te da es que estás invocando mal el método de `AssertEquals` ya que espera dos parámetros para poder compararlos, como te pone en la captura de error.
Para utilizarlo correctamente debes de poner el valor a comparar con el esperas. 
Viendo el nombre del test que quieres probar, entiendo que sería esta una implementación correcta del test:

```
  @Test
public void testGetHushCodeShortSurname(){
    Person person1 = new Person();
    person1.setAge(person1.INITIAL_AGE);
    person1.setName(person1.INITIAL_NAME);
    person1.setSurname("yi");
    assertEquals(person.getHushCode(), person1.getAge()+"-"+person1.getUpperName()+"-"+person1.getUpperSurname()+"-"+person1.getAgeCode());
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias. ya funciona